# Broken results from opencv undistort

Tags: python, opencv

I'm undistorting a sequence of images from a dataset. The dataset supplies a precalculated intrinsic matrix and distortion coefficient. When i follow the tutorial [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html), I get this result:

[image: weird image]

Which is ofcourse not what i want. When i skip the step

```
newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))
```

Then I get a good result, but the image is automatically cropped to hide the distortion of the edges which i don't want.

What's happening here and is there a way i can undistort the image without messing with the scaling?

Comment: Useful resources: [part1](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0) [part2](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-part-2-13990f1b157f)